# Show wrong route direction Alert in google maps for Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, mapkit

I am doing maps related app, in this app i am drawing route line from location to location, based on this root line user will reach his destination.But issue is i need to display alert whenever user take wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

I have one suggestion if its work for u or not but go through it once.

You check the current location is in the source and destination path 
for Eg.. your current location latitude and latitude values should check with the source and destination values.If your current location is out of range then you can display the alert message.